# Powershell script to parse a string

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

I have a string like

Set-Cookie:

`ehCookie="X0xhc3RFbnRyeVVSTENvbnRleHQ9aHR0cHM6Ly93d3c5LmNtLmVoZWFsdGhpbnN1cmFuY2UuY29tL2VoaS9ORVdCT0xvZ2luLmRzfF9MYXN0VVJMPWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3OS5jbS5laGVhbHRoaW5zdXJhbmNlLmNvbS9laGkvRGlzcGF0Y2guZnN8X0xhc3RXZWJDb250ZXh0PUJPfF9TZXNzaW9uU3RhcnQ9MDUtMjItMjAyMSAwMjoxMTo0M3xfV2ViQ29udGV4dD1CTw=="; Version=1; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly,bov1-route=1621674704.476.8922.899787; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly,JSESSIONID=304447EB52E6D43AB4ABA1191D92D07A; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly`

I want to parse the value of `ehCookie` & `JSESSIONID` like

`X0xhc3RFbnRyeVVSTENvbnRleHQ9aHR0cHM6Ly93d3c5LmNtLmVoZWFsdGhpbnN1cmFuY2UuY29tL2VoaS9ORVdCT0xvZ2luLmRzfF9MYXN0VVJMPWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3OS5jbS5laGVhbHRoaW5zdXJhbmNlLmNvbS9laGkvRGlzcGF0Y2guZnN8X0xhc3RXZWJDb250ZXh0PUJPfF9TZXNzaW9uU3RhcnQ9MDUtMjItMjAyMSAwMjoxMTo0M3xfV2ViQ29udGV4dD1CTw==`

and

`304447EB52E6D43AB4ABA1191D92D07A`

How do I go about writing a powershell script for this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like (`$str` contains the string to parse):

```
if ($str -match 'ehCookie=([^;]+).*JSESSIONID=([\dA-F]+)') {
    $ehCookie   = $matches[1]
    $jSessionId = $matches[2]
}
```

OR

```
$ehCookie   = ([regex]'(?i)ehCookie=([^;]+)').Match($str).Groups[1].Value
$jSessionId = ([regex]'(?i)JSESSIONID=([\dA-F]+)').Match($str).Groups[1].Value
```

Regex details:

```
ehCookie=       Match the characters “ehCookie=” literally
(               Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [^;]         Match any character that is NOT a “;”
      +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
.               Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *            Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
JSESSIONID=     Match the characters “JSESSIONID=” literally
(               Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   [\dA-F]      Match a single character present in the list below
                A single digit 0..9
                A character in the range between “A” and “F”
      +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

<sup>In the second example, the `(?i)` makes the `.Match` case-insensitive, which is not needed when using the `-match` operator as used in the first example</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation and taking out time to work on this